# Is there a command to check commit time in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have an ingestion_time policy enabled by default so we get ingestion_time() for every data that flows (ingested) to my ADX V3 cluster from upstream. But I would like to see how much time commit takes, so my understanding is that ingestion_time() is assigned based on when data hits Kusto, and then we have additional time that Kusto takes to commit, which can be as long as an hour as worst case scenario. So is there a command that I can use to find the difference between ingestion_time() and commit time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I have ingestion policy enabled by default*

I'm not familiar with the term "ingestion policy". you should clarify if you meant "[ingestion mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/mappings)", "[ingestion time policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/ingestiontimepolicy)", "[update policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/updatepolicy)" or something else.

> *is there a command that I can use to find the difference between ingestion_timestamp() and commit time*

In general, if you want to know when data was ingested into your Kusto table, you can use the [`ingestion_time()` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ingestiontimefunction?pivots=azuredataexplorer).

- There's no built-in function named `ingestion_timestamp()`, so your reference to that is unclear.

You won't have visibility into the exact timestamp at which transactions are committed to the database metadata

- in standard cases, the difference between that and the value of `ingestion_time()` should be negligible.

Comment: Yea ingestion_timestamp() was a typo , normally we don't type that, editor autocompletes it, so typo happened. Also corrected policy name

Comment: I am trying to export data out of kusto to storage on the basis of ingestion_time() , so I am trying to decide how much delay should I set so that I take into account all data thats has been ingested. e.g. <mytable> | where ingestion_time() between ( xxx and xxx ) , the result of that is to be exported. What if actual commit of data whose ingestion_time() falls in this range , but actual commit happens outside this range. To be safe I have kept 1 hour delay for my export. So if commit takes much longer, the ingestion_time() for that data will still reflect when it hit kusto?

Comment: *"I am trying to export data out of kusto to storage on the basis of ingestion_time()"*. instead, it's advised to use the [databse cursor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/databasecursor) to guarantee exactly-once processing. better yet, use [continuous export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/management/data-export/continuous-data-export)